# Can I see the description of a Google Calendar event without opening the event details?

Tags: google-calendar

When I click an event it shows me the title and times and attendees, but it does not show the event description.  Is there a way to see that description without opening the event details?

Comment: within the original gcal-interface?

Comment: What about an extension capable to show the description?

Comment: It is now possible. Please see [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/160427/117311)

Answer (score 4):

No, currently there is no way to see the event description without editing the event (and there are no Labs features which allow this).

[CW so that when this changes, someone can just change my answer]

Comment: It's been 6 years, WHY IS NOBODY FUNDING THIS

Comment: @Blundell because like many google products, google don't care. Just be glad google calendar hasn't been retired like google reader!

Comment: It is now possible. Please see [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/160427)

Answer (score 0):

I found this promising but partial solution:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kalendario-for-google-cal/

It seems to only show descriptions in Agenda and Search view, not the way I'd really love it - in the big empty space of event bodies in week view. Not sure why Google doesn't make this tiny change; maybe one day it will be like "hey kids, how'bout implementing it" and the next day it will be there. But I'm worried about the latest post dates here.

Comment: It is now possible. Please see [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/160427/117311)

Comment: This is not what I'm waiting for. But yes, thanks, it's there since 2016 or something, when you click the event.

Answer (score 0):

Year 2021 answer.

**It is now possible** to see the description without opening the event details.

All you need to do is **click on the event**.

[image: Event calendar description without opening the event details]

Comment: This still doesn't answer the question. The point is to be able to see the description of several calendar items at a glance without clicking anything. WORKAROUND: Put a brief description in the location field and it will show all the time. Doesn't support newlines which is really annoying.

Answer (score 0):

This isn’t really a final solution but it works you just need to copy and paste your description into the location tab and hit done it will show up on the front.